# How to store BIGINT datatype as session id using Datetime.Ticks C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, type-conversion

I'm trying to store full value of current day's `datetimeticks` to a `bigint` SQL Datatype as Session ID. But couldn't possibly convert datatype(s) successfully.

My objective is to get current `Datetime.Ticks` in C# and store it as `SessionId` in SQL Server.(version 2008 R2)

In SQL Server, I declared SessionId as `bigint` as follows:

```
[Session_Id] [bigint] NOT NULL
```

In C# (Winform), I currently use this(**working fine**):

```
long sessionId;
sessionId = Convert.ToInt64((long)BigInteger.Divide(DateTime.Now.Ticks,(BigInteger)5445654850112.1245));
```

I tried to use without truncating values from BigInteger as below but it throws error.

```
BigInteger sessionId = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```

The error of snapshot I get when I use the above code is:

[**BigInteger_Error**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzZML.png)

I also tried convert to Int64 as below but the same error persists.

```
BigInteger sessionId = Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
```

As per `MSDN` sources, size of **[BIGINT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187745.aspx)** in SQL Server is 8 bytes

> -2^63 (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808) to 2^63-1 (9,223,372,036,854,775,807)

And **BigInteger** in C# (System.Numerics) has no upper or lower bounds

Please provide alternative suggestions/fix for this error as my aim is to store full `datetimeticks` as `SessionId`

Comment: Why are you using `System.Numerics.BigInteger` when SQL `BIGINT` is equivalent to `long`/`System.Int64`?

Comment: using .Net `BigInteger` is unnecessary. You can simply save `long`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using .Net BigInteger is unnecessary. As per [SQL Server mapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) `long` maps to `BIGINT`.

```
long sessionId = DateTime.Now.Ticks
```

You have to be able to store the value of `sessionId` now in place of `[session_Id] BIGINT NOTNULL`

Comment: Oops.Simple logic. Thank you for letting me notice that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, casting BigInteger is redundant as `long (Int64)` means `BIGINT` in SQL Server. Second, you can simply set your `sessionId` value to your Ticks as long as the data type is long. You are basically casting the same type two times for no reason.

```
//Timespan.Ticks is a long data type.
long sessionId = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
```